# mvc4 acting as a gateway

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http, asp.net-mvc-routing

what i want to achieve is:

1. a central server connected to the database, using entity framework
2. a server who for some reason can't reach the database but forward the requests to the central server (not all of them only the one who require the database)
3. some httpclients who can't reach the central server nor the database but only the middle server

I've already tried with success modifying the controller method to create an http client who redo the reuest to the cenral server, but that seems the worst way to me, especially because i've lots of controllers and methods

```
public User GetUser(int id)
{
    if (Properties.Settings.Default.SyncEnabled)
    {
        System.Net.Http.HttpClient httpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
        httpClient.BaseAddress = Properties.Settings.Default.SyncAddress;
        var result = httpClient.GetAsync(this.Request.Url.PathAndQuery).Result;
        return this.Content(result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result, result.Content.Headers.ContentType.MediaType);
    }
    else
    {
        User user = DbContext.Users.Find(id);
        user.LastOnline = DateTime.Now;
        DbContext.SaveChanges();
        return user;
    }
}
```

i was thinking about using register route, but i'd like to know if it's a good idea, before reading how routes works...
i'm also intrested in how would you implement that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since nobody gave me an answer i'm gonna suggest myself to try with this:

http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing

seems that reverse proxy can do the trick, but i need to do it with two separate iis